# how to relogin and link to specified webpage with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have two passwords A and B on the same website, sometimes login with password A and sometimes login with password B, whatever use password A or B, after login I need to link to one specified web page, but always stops after login and do not execute subsequent code. Below is my code, I tried to different functions but failed, I don't know what's problem with these code, please help, many thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def login():

    driver.get('website_url')

    while True:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Account"]').send_keys('Username')
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Password"]').send_keys('Password A')
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="loginBtn"]').click()
        time.sleep(3)

        # if password A login failed, using password B

        try:
            strl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="field-validation-error"]').text
        
            if strl == "Password Error":
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Account"]').clear()
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Account"]').send_keys('Username')
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Password"]').send_keys('Password B')
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="loginBtn"]').click()
                time.sleep(3)

        except:
            print('Login Successfully!')
            return driver
login()
```

Always stop here and do not execute subsequent code

```
# This is where the main execution code starts.

def main():
    driver.get('webpage_url')

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes that I see:

1- What is the reason of *try-except*? I cannot see any exception in the code.

2- You defined `driver` as global variable but you are returning it from the `login` function. So, this seems illogical. Also, you are not assigning this return value to any variable.

3- Usage of `time.sleep()` is a bad practice but I assume that these are only for debugging.

4- `while True:` statement creates an endless loop.

My advices:

1- You should remove *try-except* completely and only use *if-else* for this.

2- Remove `return` statement from the `login` function.

3- Define an entry point to your program such as `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

4- Remove `while True:` statement which creates an endless loop or use it carefully.

Putting all together:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def login():

    driver.get('website_url')

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Account"]').send_keys('Username')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Password"]').send_keys('Password A')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="loginBtn"]').click()
    time.sleep(3)

    # if password A login failed, using password B

    strl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="field-validation-error"]').text
        
    if strl == "Password Error":
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Account"]').clear()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Account"]').send_keys('Username')
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Password"]').send_keys('Password B')
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="loginBtn"]').click()
        time.sleep(3)

    print('Login Successfully!')


def main():

    login()
    driver.get('website_url')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Many thanks for reply.

What is the reason of `try-except`?
>>When the password A is successfully logged in, it should be connect the web page `driver.get('website_url')`, but it was stuck in this code `strl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="field-validation-error"]').text` can't execute program, so I use `try-except` to resolve this problem...

Usage of time.sleep() is a bad practice but I assume that these are only for debugging.
>>Do you have any better suggestion? 

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Okay I understand your _try-except_. This is somewhat weird because normally, _try-except_ is used to handle unwanted situations but you handle desired situation with it. It works but maybe, you can try to change its logic to find successful logins and if it fails, then throw an exception. Also, you should only except `NoSuchElementException`. Catching all exceptions is totally bad practice. You should check visibility of elements instead of `time.sleep()` function.

Comment: The main problem with your code was `while True:` statement. You don't _break_ this loop anywhere, which causes an infinite loop. You can use an additional _if_ statement to do this but I don't recommend to use infinite loop. Instead, you should use a for loop and define a try count. For example, try to login 5 times and if it fails, then you can throw an exception.

Comment: Many thanks for kindly suggestions! I will try to fix these problems. :)